# X-Frame-Options not explicitly set to sameorigin, but Nginx blocking rendering page into iframe

Tags: php, nginx, x-frame-options

I did not explicitly set anywhere in nginx the x-frame-options to sameorigin but nginx is blocking the html page rendered inside an iframe. Tried specifying the domain in the X-Frame-Options but no luck. Giving several errors in the console if that helps. I read through them and tried fixes but not working.

https://preview.codecanyon.net/item/product-name/product-id

It previews my HTML page in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about X-Frame-Options but [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) also. Codecanyon set an CSP header that prevent the other sites can frame in their site. Even you allow all sites in your XFO header, they can block your site display in their website with CSP header.

But they are a market, they have to open a way for developer to include an iframe in their preview page. Seems they're not implemented a way for developer provide frame-src in preview page. So Codecanyon's CSP header is in Report only mode. All things is running fine although a lot of error you see from Chrome Developer Console.

[image]

---

By the way, you implemented an syntax error CSP header: unexpected punctuation at the start.

Comment: I noticed that. Any idea where I  caused that? In the nginx config file? Nginx is not complaining.hard to find.

Comment: Nginx will not complain header's value.

Comment: Got it. I had a : after the CSP Header name.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I later figured out that setting frame-ancestors to that specific domain allowed that domain to show the page in an iframe. You can do that in the nginx config  file.